# How to debug windows phone 8 app in remote system?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I am working on project.  I have taken remote system.  My problem is that Visual studio and windows phone 8 device located in remote place.   Windows phone 8 is connected in remote server.   All sources and devices are located in remote server.   I need to test and debug the app.  How can i see the device screen?   I want to control the device using remote server.  Any software or method to take control the phone in PC?

In other words,  I want to control or display the screen of windows phone 8 device on PC.

Any idea should help me a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is what emulators are for.

Comment: Ok...  Emulator is using for development. when the app is going to testing in device?  How will i do?

Comment: Remotely, you can't. People set up cameras to display screen or use emulators. I don't understand how you would interact with the phone remotely?

Comment: actually, windows mobile 6.5 uses soti software used to display the screen in pc.  We can support remote customer from here.

Comment: That doesn't work in 7+ unless you have access to the private Microsoft-employee only builds of the phone.

Comment: What is the actual scenario? You make it sound like it's for general support, but why would Visual Studio be installed? To use VS, and do remote debugging, the phone would need to be registered as a development device.

Comment: Actually, I am decided to work on remote.  They are having all resources and not allowing to go outside their source code.....

Answer (score 0):

As there is not a way to interact with a physical Windows phone 8 remotely yet (unless you are a Microsoft employee with special access to private builds of the phone), I'd suggest that the remote site set up a machine configured with Windows 8.1, Hyper-V, Visual Studio for Windows Phone, and the emulators. You can use Remote Desktop to gain access to the machine and test and debug the application through the emulators.

Or, of course, the best would be if you could just gain access to the source code for the application and do the testing locally. Depending on the resources required by the application, you may need to create a LAN to LAN VPN in which all traffic would route through the remote site.